# Applying 'for' in the list by fives

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I want to apply a 'for' in a list by fives.

For example;

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for a in list:
    print(a)
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

After these 5 ends, i want it to move to the second 5.

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "apply a for"?

Comment: Your current code does exactly that.  It iterates over the first 5 elements, and then the next 5.  Perhaps you need to clarify what you actually want.

Comment: Sorry about that. For example; I have two function. First function return all list. (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
In the second function, I want to print (or do something) the first 5 items of this list, then the second 5 items. and I want it to continue 5 by 5 until the list is finished.

Answer (score 0):

It seems extremely non-idiomatic to write code like this, but perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
t = iter(a)
try:
    while True:
        counter = 1
        while i := t.__next__():
            print(i)
            if counter == 5:
                break
            counter += 1
        print("Finished group")
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

you may be looking for this in collections

chunked(iterable, n) returns an iterable of lists, each of length n (except the last one, which may be shorter);

ichunked(iterable, n) is similar but returns an iterable of iterables instead.